# How to switch to an inactive Chrome tab?

Tags: python, selenium, windows-10, pywinauto

On Windows 10 using Python 3.x, I want to be able to switch focus to a specific Chrome tab (Google Meet) that is guaranteed to uniquely exist, but which may not currently be the active tab. And I'd like to be able to switch to this tab directly, rather than (say) iterating through all open tabs until I randomly hit upon it.

Comment: They are called handles and I'm sure that it isn't currently possible due to how they work.

Comment: Your code trials please